# Connecting to a SQL Server database with Python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I am trying to connect from Python to a Microsoft SQL Server database. I have already installed the driver `msoledbsql_18.2.2.0_x64.msi` and I followed the instructions given in the anaconda website "https://www.anaconda.com/anaconda-easy-button-microsoft-sql-server-and-python/##client-driver-installation".

But nothing runs and I checked out some answers in this community but I still get the same error:

> OperationalError: ('08001', "[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Ce serveur SQL n'existe pas ou son accès est refusé. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)")

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
sql_conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=DESKTP-L51003R; DATABASE=BambinosDataBase; Trusted_Connection=yes") 
query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Visiteur]"
df = pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)
```

Comment: Your connection string is probably not correct - check if you can access the sql server from management studio using the same server and database names

Comment: Double check what driver you should be using -- for me it's `r'{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'`

Comment: ping DESKTP-L51003R or telnet DESKTP-L51003R 443 is resolving correct ip server ?